# how do I test the relationship between infection and nurse:patient ratio

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I am evaluating whether the prevalence of a specific infection in the ICU bears a relationship to the nurse:patient ratio over time.
The infections are whole numbers (nominal variable)and the nurse: patient ratio is also a number (ratio variable).

Comment: You could consider a GLM (perhaps staring with Poisson regression), or negative binomial or zero-inflated Poisson regression. There's likely to be time dependence as well, in which case things become a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok lets analyze your problem.
1. Types of variables: Looks like you have two ratio variables.
2. What is their relation: correlation
3. What statistic would be fit:

Normally in this case we would use a Pearson Product-Moment correlation.

It would be nice if you could share if the relation between those variables is monotonic and is it linear. ALWAYS LOOK AT THE DATA FIRST!

In case it is non monotonic or non linear - some other test could be a better fit.

for non-linear i would try Spearmans-rank test.